# Background CSS issue and MENU Hyperlink

Tags: css, menu, background, anchor

I used a wordpress template to start off my journey. I cant turn back now on the template due to time. I am very aware that Wordpress is a simple tool to use and I do understand that it's not ideal in most cases.

I created this website www.robbenislandfence.com but am challenged with the following 2 concerns.
If one hovers over MY ORDER and NOTIFY ME SERVICE, a "text anchor" icon appears. Does NOT look good at all, It should trigger the hand icon as seen on the above links. What can I do to get the hand to show up on these 2 menu items of the menu?

The second question I have is, 
I want to go into the background.css doc and remove the large image (bridge.jpg - which actually is the image of the fence) and just replace it with a color.

Can I just simply replace the bridge.css script below:

```
#page {
 background: url(../../images/background/bridge/bridge.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
 background: 
 url(../../images/background/texture/tv_70.png) 0 0 repeat fixed,
 url(../../images/background/bridge/bridge.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed,
 #9fbfa8;
 background-size: auto, cover;
 }

 @media (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

 #page {
 background-image: none; 
 background-color: #9fbfa8;
 }

 }
```

with this following one below:

```
#page { background: #1a1a1a; }
```

Will it mess up the website if I delete the entire first css script above and replace everything with this 1 liner of script?

```
#page { background: #1a1a1a; }
```

(I just want a charcoal bkg color to show up, not the fence background image seen on the site. I think it's causing problems with the speed of the pages on the site)

The website seems slow and I think it has to do with the 3 background images duplicated as seen in the css script above. I am not sure. Each background image is around 280-350kb so it all adds up. It's very important that there is hardly a delay on the download time of the webpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on hover for the item simply use the css attribute for cursor known as "pointer". Applying this css attribute to elements will add "the hand"

```
 a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

For the background, the code you have looks correct. Test it out. 
Images usually are the culprit when it comes to a slow website. In photoshop there is a "save for web" option that will help you out.

to comment out css code:

```
#page {
     background: url(someImage);
}
```

Same code commented out:

```
/**
 #page {
     background: url(someImage);
}
**/
```

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for the feedback. If I do away totally with that long script and add in the short one, it will work right? If something goes wrong can I put the old script back in? Will it default backto the original look? I cant afford to have an error right now. Just double checking if you know what I mean :) Dion

Comment: any changes made in an editor can usually be removed with "ctrl + z". Also, make a backup. Better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Hi David, this long code above looks like there is duplication in it so it may be uploading 2-3 images in the background? Can I do away with any of that code? I dont want the texture to show and I would like to get rid of the duplicated image. The reason why I am asking is that the client may not want to do away with the image. But it looks like there are too many background images that can be deleted right now to speed the site up alittle more. What do you think. Many thx again for you help. So appreciated. Dion

Comment: Multiple backgrounds are possible in css3. Simply comment out the background images for now with /** Code to be commented out **/

Comment: Sorry David, You mean like this:

#page {
 background: url(**/**/**/**/**/**) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
 background: 
 url(**/**/**/**/**/**) 0 0 repeat fixed,
 url(**/**/**/**/**/**) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed,
 #9fbfa8;
 background-size: auto, cover;
 }

 @media (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

 #page {
 background-image: none; 
 background-color: #9fbfa8;
 }

 }

Comment: No. /** background-size: auto, cover; **/ that code will not longer be active. Any code in css can be commented out this way.

Comment: Hey David, I am missing you in something. If I take that long original code and do away with all the images and only have a background image. What would the code look like with the **. Can you possibly show me the breakdown from my code. I serious dont understand what you mean. Thanks alot.

Comment: Last time I will comment on this. See above code. Also, do not forget to vote for one of the answers here.

Comment: Thx again David. I tried to rather chat, but it wouldnt allow me to.

Comment: Oh David, How do I get you guys to advice me again. I had the image but want to change the green colour to black in the background bridge.css and when I uploaded I got the background black but the image is now missing. I uploaded the original css and the background image is still missing and its coming up with the green again. I dont know how to fix this now. It basically didnt restore.

Answer (score 0):

use the css "cursor" property to change the cursor on a hovered element:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

will give you the hand (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

As for the second part of your question, yes, replacing that code with the hex color code should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Brian, I only now realised that it cant have the hand cursor because it opens up the subscriber window and the other to the right when you hover over those 2 links. It still looks kind of odd to me. You cant click on those sections, silly me. Wish it wasnt an anchor though, an arrow pointing to the right would be better :) What do you think. Thanks again for your help aswell. Dion

Comment: Hi Brian, I am not sure who is around. I am going to try ask everyone and hopefully someone will be able to advise me. I had the image but want to replace the green colour to black in the background bridge.css and when I uploaded I got the background black but the image and the thatch effect is not loading on the homepage.It seems to be loading on all the other pages. www.robbenislandfence.com When I saw this not working, I uploaded the original css and the background image and thatch effect is still not popping in on the homepage. Pls can u help? Many thx Dion

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why is it when I hover over MY ORDER and NOTIFY ME SERVICE the text cursor appears instead of the pointer.**

This is simply because those two are not actually links.  Because of this, the default text cursor is used.  I wouldn't recommend using a pointer as that indicates those can be clicked, when in your case they cannot (again, they are not links).  This may confuse users who are familiar with that cursor appearing on click-able elements.

You can change the default cursor by applying a class to the following:

In **/wp-content/themes/yoo_showroom_wp-1/css/menus.css** on Line 36, look for and add `cursor: pointer;`

```
.menu-dropdown a.level1, .menu-dropdown span.level1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**2. Can I just simply replace the bridge.css script with a background color definition.**

Yes.  This will not have any negative impacts.  The changes you've outlined should work if done correctly.

Comment: Hi Axel, Many thanks for your feedback. I will download a the bridge.css to my computer and replace the bridge.css file with this script > #page { background: #1a1a1a; } only. If something goes wrong which everyone here says wont, I will upload the original script back and hopefully it will default back to show the previous background image. Thats the plan. You can tell I am nervous right now. thx again Dion

Comment: Hi Axel, I am not sure who is around. I am going to try ask everyone and hopefully someone will be able to advise me. I had the image but want to replace the green colour to black in the background bridge.css and when I uploaded I got the background black but the image and the thatch effect is not loading on the homepage.It seems to be loading on all the other pages. www.robbenislandfence.com When I saw this not working, I uploaded the original css and the background image and thatch effect is still not popping in on the homepage. Any help from you will be gr8. Many thx Dion

Answer (score 0):

For the menu hover:

in class:

```
.menu-dropdown a.level1 > span, .menu-dropdown span.level1 > span
```

add

```
cursor: pointer
```

(menus.css line 39)

and for the background image, yes, what you suggested will work fine.

Comment: Hi Pat, I am just hoping nothing will kick out with an error, so I need to be certain it will work. I am going with what you say. thx again, Dion

Comment: Hi Pat, I am not sure who is around. I am going to try ask everyone and hopefully someone will be able to advise me. I had the image but want to replace the green colour to black in the background bridge.css and when I uploaded I got the background black but the image and the thatch effect is not loading on the homepage.It seems to be loading on all the other pages. www.robbenislandfence.com When I saw this not working, I uploaded the original css and the background image and thatch effect is still not popping in on the homepage. Any help from you will be gr8. Many thx Dion